# How to Handle multipart/form-data request without express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, multipartform-data, boundary

So I have this form:

```
  <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="name" title="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
      <input id="quantity" title="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
      <input id="price" title="price" type="text" placeholder="price" />
      <input id="imageLocation" title="imageLocation" type="text" placeholder="imagelocation" />
      <input id="description" title="description" type="text" placeholder="description" />
  </form>
```

Here Is where I send the data:

```
 function postMultiPartHttpCall() {
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    var FD = new FormData(form);

    XHR.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
        var callingObj = {};
        callingObj.responseText = event.target.responseText;
        console.log(callingObj);
    });

    XHR.open("POST", '/articlePost');
    XHR.send(FD);
}
```

And here is where I receive it:

```
    function _processFormData (request, res, onSuccess,onError) {
    var requestBody = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        requestBody += data;
        if (requestBody.length > 1e7) {
            res.writeHead(413, 'Request length too long', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end('413 : Request Entity Too Large');
        }
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        var oFormData = qsLib.parse(requestBody);
        console.log(request.headers);

    });
}
```

So when I send some data I receive this (console.log):

```
Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858
Server was started
{ host: 'localhost:1337',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'content-length': '44',
origin: 'http://localhost:1337',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyVFw7KZwIaAIQeQ1',
accept: '*/*',
referer: 'http://localhost:1337/CartSPA.html',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,hr;q=0.6,de-AT;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,de-DE;q=0.2' }
```

So what I want is to get an object with the fields of form without using expressJS or other similar 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries. Is it possible to get the attributes using the boundary number or where can I see which data was sent?

Comment: Why is the encoding type of the form _multipart/form-data_? Do you plan to send file data (e.g. Uploaded by the user)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is "*possible to get the attributes using the boundary number*", though you will have to match the fields and parse out the names manually...

Also, in order to have the values from the form get sent, the attribute [*name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-name) needs to be set on the [input tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). For example:

```
<input id="quantity" title="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
```

Should be updated to contain a *name* attribute, like below:

```
<input name="quantity" id="quantity" title="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity" />
```

With the name attributes set on the form fields, the body of the request should contain the form data (i.e. `requestBody` should then have the contents of the encoded form when the data is done being loaded). For example, it may look similar to the output below:

```
-----------------------------150182554619156
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

z4520
-----------------------------150182554619156
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"

2
-----------------------------150182554619156
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

32.90
-----------------------------150182554619156
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagelocation"

/img/z4520.jpg
-----------------------------150182554619156
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

water filter
-----------------------------150182554619156--
```

###Parsing out the form fields

In the starter code below, it checks the request header **Content-Type** for the  *boundary* (you might also want to ensure the Content-Type is in fact "*multipart/form-data*") using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and then sets the boundary using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and taking the 2nd element from the resultant array. That boundary value can be used to separate the body data into an array (also using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).

I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to parse out the values and store them in an array (see `@TODO`; ).

<sub>*Hint:* [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) might come in very handy...</sub>

```
request.on('end', function() {
    if (request.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-type') && request.headers['content-type'].indexOf('boundary=') > -1) {
        var parts = request.headers['content-type'].split('boundary=');
        var boundary = parts[1];
        var splitBody = requestBody.split(boundary);
        /**
         @TODO: iterate over elements in splitBody, matching name and value and add to array of fields
        */

        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.write(JSON.stringify({formFields: splitBody}));
    }
    else {
        //bad request
        res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.write("missing boundary in content-type"));
    }
    res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: @SergeyYaratskiy is it possible without using any libraries? So that I can the form data just by using boundary number or content-disposition?

Comment: For sure, from library I gave you, check out file https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/lib/incoming_form.js#L273,   start from line 273 for example.

Comment: hmm I still need user libraries such as multipart_parser

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the npm module [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty). It is pretty straight forward.

In your request handler, do something like this.

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
```

Comment: is it possible using it without any libraries. So just splitting the boundary or get the data using content-disposition

Comment: Of course you can. But you have to parse the whole HTTP request including the headers.Can i ask why you don't want to use modules? If they are pure JS modules then there is really no difference if you use them or write it yourself.
p.s Sorry I hate to be that guy, who says "why are you doing it like that" when there may be a good reason.

Comment: I know, but in the school project in which I am involved we aren't allowed to use any libraries. So basically we should rebuild a module. I don't know why...